# The NPM global flag seems to be inconsistent on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

Runnin from the console

```
> npm root -g
```

Or programmatically

```
var npm = require("npm");
npm.load(null, function (err, npm) {
    npm.config.set("global", true);
    npm.root;
});
```

I get a different results on Windows. The first one returns `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and the second one `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules`. The same happens when I install a module, doing this programmatically tries to install it on program files instead of AppData.

Could this be a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

On linux it works consistently. I've not tried on Mac.

**Update:** I tried this on Mac and it works fine.

Comment: I've had this happen in an older version of NPM.  What version are you using?

Comment: 1.2.10 (note: SO wants comments to be at least 15 characters so I had to add this note)

Comment: This happens too with node 0.10.20 and an `npm install -g npm` after that. At least if the node wasn't a clean install. Maybe in that case it doesn't happen? The npmrc mentioned in the answer didn't even exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference appears to be the `npmrc` that's included in the Node.js install for Windows:

```
# C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc

prefix=${APPDATA}\npm
```

It's path positions it to be handled [as a `builtin` config](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/v1.2.10/lib/npm.js#L270-L271), rather than a [global](https://github.com/isaacs/npmconf/blob/v0.0.23/config-defs.js#L205) or [user](https://github.com/isaacs/npmconf/blob/v0.0.23/config-defs.js#L261) config, so "*local*" installs of `npm` won't process it. You can see this when executing the local install directly:

```
> .\node_modules\.bin\npm root -g
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules
```

Comment: Should this be changed? Or should the locally installed npm include a similar npmrc?

Comment: @MiguelMadero Whether or not it should be changed would likely be up to [`isaacs`](https://github.com/isaacs), [el al.](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/contributors) It may be worthwhile [submitting an issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues) for it; see how they respond.

Comment: I raised [the issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3155). So far, no answer. Thanks